# How to get all validators in the page?

Tags: asp.net

I thought RequiredFieldValidators, CustomValidators, and all other validators would live in Controls collection. Basically I have a User Control that has a number of validators in it, and I would like to get a handle on them to do stuff.

Page.Validators seem to return a list of IValidator objects, which are not what I am looking for.

Where can I get the list of all validators in a User Control?

Comment: The `Controls` collection isn't deep (i.e. immediate children only), but you can easily write your own method to recurse through all controls in the hierarchy.

Comment: Very nice catch. I did not know a <td runat="server"> is a container.

Answer (score 2):

The Page.Validators collection is your best bet; all validators implement IValidator, and in turn, BaseValidator, so you can use this do to that.  Since the validator is a control, it's parent reference trail will contain a reference to the user control it lives in.  It may require you doing something like:

```
if (validator.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent is UserControl) { }
```

But that is the only way to figure that out.  So a combination of Page.Validators, and checking the parent control tree is the only way, unless you look for specific validation groups that a validator implements, which also is another way (a property of BaseValidator, so you'll have to do a type check and cast.

There is one last potential option; you can override AddedControl, which executes on every control add, and check if the control is a validator, and then keep that control in a local collection like:

```
private List<BaseValidator> _vals = ..;

protected overrides void AddedControl(Control control, int index) {
   if (control is BaseValidator)
     _vals.Add((BaseValidator)control);
}
```

Then you would know which controls belong to that user control.  I've done this with custom controls, not anything with user controls, so may not work exactly as I mentioned...

Comment: Page.Validators is a collection of IValidators, which have no Parent. It woulda been nice though.

Comment: IValidator is really BaseValidator, a control, which does have a parent property.  Just because it's an IValidator, doesn't mean it isn't usable.  You have to get to the underlying type.  Also, to ensure you only get basevalidators, you can do Page.Validators.OfType<BaseValidator>()

Comment: Couldn't you do something like this: Page.Validators.OfType<BaseValidator>().Where(ctrl => ctrl.ControlToValidate == YOUR_USER_CONTROL_ID);

Comment: @Jfetner No because validators don't target user controls; the OP is looking for validators pointing to standard textbox/ddl/etc controls within the user control, from what I gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using ASP.NET validation controls you might be looking for a validation summary:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.validationsummary%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

You can do quite a bit with it fitting most usage scenarios, here's a simple example:

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/10/validationsummary-example-how-to-use.html

Alternatively, Page.Validators would provide direct access.